# How to send commit e-mails in Collabnet Subversion Edge via SMTP with SSL

Tags: svn, version-control, collabnet

We can successfully setup sending commit e-mails, by adding a post commit hook to a repository, via SMTP. However this only works when the SMTP connection does not use SSL. We are going to lose our non-SSL SMTP server soon, so we're moving everything to use the SSL based SMTP connection.

However, if we use the server settings for SSL (port 465), including using full user name and password, collabnet can not send any e-mails, it returns with an error saying Connection Closed Unexpectedly.

It seems to me that the python libraries included with Collabnet Subversion Edge does not support SSL SMTP. Can anybody confirm?

Any other alternatives that we can use?

Edit: We are on Win7, x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to send emails on Subversion commits is to use the hook script provided by Subversion.  Details of running that script on Windows are here:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/CommitMailerOnWin32

It sounds like you have this working successfully, but just making sure this is the hook you are using.

I am not aware of this hook not supporting SSL.  It uses Python to send the message so would likely just be based on what Python mail module supports.  It seems like it would support this.  I suppose there are other hook scripts out there, I know there is one in Perl.